# Syntax tree validation uncertainty

Tags: logic, trees

The validation of a formula can be represented through syntax trees.

1. ¬ (A, B∧C)

The reason I am confused is because of the comma.
I think the formula is valid.

Let us consider.

A= She eats
B= She sleeps
C= She drinks

¬ (A, B∧C) <=> She doesn't eat. She doesn't sleep and drink.

2. A¬ (B ∧ C)

I think the formula is Wrong.
It could have been correct is a comma would have been involved or another biding operator.

A¬ (B ∧ A) <=> She eats She doesn't sleep and eats.

This would not be able to be represented in a Syntax tree

Comment: No, the comma is not a propositional connective.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, after reserching I did find out that comma is not a connective. For punctuation only braces are allowed.
I am not sure on the second one.

Comment: Also the second is wrong.

Comment: The syntax tree must be built using the syntactical specifications of the definition of *formula*. Without them, we can only uses common sense.